# Crapsaccharine world

Tags: civilization, secret-society

Any ideas on how to make a convincing crapsaccharine world? I'm scared mine might be too obvious. In the world I'm building hundreds of mythological beasts live in a feigned harmony but under the surface the queen has been using the underlying grudges there are between certain races , e.g vampires and werewolves. I want to make it seem as in the place is completely wonderful ,but for the antagonistic nature to seep in slowly.

TV tropes article to explain them [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrapsaccharineWorld).

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding and hats-off to your username. As it stands this question is very broad and quite hard to answer as a result. To get better responses it could be helpful to share a little information on the direction you have worked in so far and what your goals are for the world.

Comment: Asking for ideas is most likely to get the question closed. I would suggest explaining in details the setting you want, and precising what you aren't able to explain. Not by asking how to make it better, but let's say asking, how could a ruling entity X manage to convince any outsider that PerfectWorld3000 is close to a living utopia when in reality every single instant of it's inhabitants lives is scripted and any divergence from that script is heavily punished. Again the more you put details the better.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try too hard. I know that is one of the stupidest pieces of advice but bear with me.

Firstly, don't rush it. Let the reader (assuming it is a book) into this world, let them become invested in the happy atmosphere. Just be subtle with the darkness until it becomes clear that there is something dark underlying the entire situation. Rushing something is something that can and often is the killer for the mood.

Secondly, make sure you know what is happening underneath the surface at all times, even if you never reveal these details to the reader. This is important to determining what happens and why. Having something happen and there being no plausable reason for it makes the activity seem forced. I find that writing two seperate timelines and making them merge at some point works well as you can plan what happens in both timelines and work out how they interconnect.

Comment: :P  write two stories, one about a totalitarian system slowly succeeding in being put in place. A loss of freedom, a dark and terrible story line. And the second one a seemingly joyous storyline with no hints whatsoever of anything being wrong. Tell the two stories side by side and the first will kinda of synch the feeling somethings wrong every time you switch to the second. In the end, you learn the first becomes the second (reaches the beginning of the second story) and at the end of the second finally its revealed something IS wrong and because of that there's is hope since its known.